# Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard - Cannot download Windows Updates

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-update

I'm attempting to update a production server that hasn't had a Windows Update installed in almost 3 years.

When I attempt to download any update, even if I select just one, the download hangs at 0% consistently. The first time I downloaded the updates (97 updates), it hung at 46% for 12+hrs.

I stopped the download, restarted the computer, restarted the Windows update, and ever since then, it hangs at 0%.

[image]

The event log is indicating that the installer, *TrustedInstaller.exe*, is crashing everytime I try to re-download the updates.

```
Faulting application name: TrustedInstaller.exe, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5bc4b0
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385, time stamp: 0x4a5be02b
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000000000055237
Faulting process id: 0x10b0
Faulting application start time: 0x01d23c2c67a04444
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\servicing\TrustedInstaller.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: a8423514-a81f-11e6-9286-b8ac6f92c237
```

Note: The other day, it let me know that I would need to download an update to the installer before installing Window's updates (humourous).

I ran this, and I'm not sure if it was successful or not, but I would assume so, since I was able to start downloading the updates up to 46%.

[image]

At this point I'm wondering if I should just install SP1 directly on the server. I assume it's a roll-up of all the major updates since, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Manually download the last version of windows update client and apply it, retry after.

Answer (score 2):

Check your windowsupdate.log (C:\Windows) for errors.

Stop Windows Update and BITS services

Delete C:\Windows\Software Distribution folder

Reset your WMI Repository --> Open CMD and type winmgmt /resetrepository

Start BITS and Windows Updates services

Try again.

Answer (score 2):

You may try to rebuild download database.

This topic may help you with it:

https://xunyangit.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/cant-download-any-updates-on-windows-server-2008-r2/

Answer (score 0):

Is the server idle or not? I thought that updates downloaded via BITS (Background Intelligent Transfer Service), which means only (or trying to) in idle time.
Try to reboot and just leave it, it can take hours but try to keep the server idle as much as possible.